# How to assign a string value to an array in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

When I try to assign a string to an array like this:

```
CoverageACol[0,0] = "Hello"
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    CoverageACol[0,0] = "hello"
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

However, assigning an integer does not result in an error:

```
CoverageACol[0,0] = 42
```

CoverageACol is a numpy array.

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You get the error because NumPy's array is [homogeneous, meaning it is a multidimensional table of elements all of the same type](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-d3f8e5fe9b903f3c3b2a5c0dfceb60d71602cf93). This is different from a multidimensional list-of-lists in "regular" Python, where you can have objects of different type in a list.

**Regular Python:**

```
>>> CoverageACol = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                    [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
 
>>> CoverageACol[0][0] = "hello"

>>> CoverageACol
    [['hello', 1, 2, 3, 4], 
     [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

**NumPy:**

```
>>> from numpy import *

>>> CoverageACol = arange(10).reshape(2,5)

>>> CoverageACol
    array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
           [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

>>> CoverageACol[0,0] = "Hello" 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/biogeek/<ipython console> in <module>()

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

So, it depends on what you want to achieve, why do you want to store a string in an array filled for the rest with numbers? If that really is what you want, you can set the datatype of the NumPy array to string:

```
>>> CoverageACol = array(range(10), dtype=str).reshape(2,5)

>>> CoverageACol
    array([['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'],
           ['5', '6', '7', '8', '9']], 
           dtype='|S1')

>>> CoverageACol[0,0] = "Hello"

>>> CoverageACol
    array([['H', '1', '2', '3', '4'],
         ['5', '6', '7', '8', '9']], 
         dtype='|S1')
```

Notice that only the first letter of `Hello` gets assigned. If you want the whole word to get assigned, you need to set [an array-protocol type string](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html):

```
>>> CoverageACol = array(range(10), dtype='a5').reshape(2,5)

>>> CoverageACol: 
    array([['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'],
           ['5', '6', '7', '8', '9']], 
           dtype='|S5')

>>> CoverageACol[0,0] = "Hello"

>>> CoverageACol
    array([['Hello', '1', '2', '3', '4'],
           ['5', '6', '7', '8', '9']], 
           dtype='|S5')
```

Comment: Setting `dtype=object` also works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639496/python-numpy-array-of-arbitrary-length-strings

Comment: In your line `overageACol = array(range(10), dtype=str).reshape(2,5)`. Is possible to change `dtype` to `list` or `dict`?

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the [data type](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) of the [array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

```
CoverageACol = numpy.array([["a","b"],["c","d"]],dtype=numpy.dtype('a16'))
```

This makes ConerageACol an array of strings (a) of length 16.