# How to create a numpy array of arbitrary length strings?

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I'm a complete rookie to Python, but it seems like a given string is able to be (effectively) arbitrary length.  i.e. you can take a `string str` and keeping adding to it: `str += "some stuff..."`.  Is there a way to make an array of such strings?

When I try this, each element only stores a single character

```
strArr = numpy.empty(10, dtype='string')
for i in range(0,10)
    strArr[i] = "test"
```

On the other hand, I know I can initialize an array of certain length strings, i.e.

```
strArr = numpy.empty(10, dtype='s256')
```

which can store 10 strings of up to 256 characters.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You can do so by creating an array of `dtype=object`. If you try to assign a long string to a normal numpy array, it truncates the string:

```
>>> a = numpy.array(['apples', 'foobar', 'cowboy'])
>>> a[2] = 'bananas'
>>> a
array(['apples', 'foobar', 'banana'], 
      dtype='|S6')
```

But when you use `dtype=object`, you get an array of python object references. So you can have all the behaviors of python strings:

```
>>> a = numpy.array(['apples', 'foobar', 'cowboy'], dtype=object)
>>> a
array([apples, foobar, cowboy], dtype=object)
>>> a[2] = 'bananas'
>>> a
array([apples, foobar, bananas], dtype=object)
```

Indeed, because it's an array of objects, you can assign *any* kind of python object to the array:

```
>>> a[2] = {1:2, 3:4}
>>> a
array([apples, foobar, {1: 2, 3: 4}], dtype=object)
```

However, this undoes a lot of the benefits of using numpy, which is so fast because it works on large contiguous blocks of raw memory. Working with python objects adds a lot of overhead. A simple example:

```
>>> a = numpy.array(['abba' for _ in range(10000)])
>>> b = numpy.array(['abba' for _ in range(10000)], dtype=object)
>>> %timeit a.copy()
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.51 us per loop
>>> %timeit b.copy()
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.4 us per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, your first example is especially helpful--I never would have guessed that behavior!  I'm not worried about the speed for this object, so slower access should be fine.

Comment: Nice answer.  I've incorporated a link to it with demo into a python notebook page I'm working on about numpy array creation.

Comment: @senderle if an array is with ``object`` dtype, then ``np.fromstring(arr.tostring())`` will fail with ``numpy Cannot create an object array from a string``. Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: @游凯超 hmm. That's a tough one. It's not a total surprise because numpy really isn't designed to work with python objects. It's more of a shortcut than a proper use of numpy. So there's no real reason for them to support corner cases like that. My approach would probably be to get the maximum length of string and use a standard fixed-width char array.

Comment: @游凯超 if your goal is to use strings as row labels or column headers you should also look into [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).

Answer (score 24):

You could use the object data type:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> s = numpy.array(['a', 'b', 'dude'], dtype='object')
>>> s[0] += 'bcdef'
>>> s
array([abcdef, b, dude], dtype=object)
```

Comment: note that doing this you can't use https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.char.html anymore