# H5py store list of list of strings

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

Is there a possibility in h5py to create a dataset which consists of lists of strings. I tried to create a nested datatype of variable length, but this results in segmentation fault in my python interpreter.

```
def create_dataset(h5py_file):
    data = [['I', 'am', 'a', 'sentecne'], ['another', 'sentence']]
    string_dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)
    nested_dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=string_dt)
    h5py_file.create_dataset("sentences", data=data, dtype = nested_dt)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you don't intend to edit the hdf5 file (and potentially use longer strings), you can also simply use:

```
h5py_file.create_dataset("sentences", data=np.array(data, dtype='S'))
```

Comment: This will also will lead to problems if your data contains non-ASCII characters, read more about storing strings in HDF here: http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/strings.html

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the functionality you want if you define your data as a numpy array of dtype=object as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639496/python-numpy-array-of-arbitrary-length-strings), rather than a list of lists.

```
def create_dataset(h5py_file):
    data = np.array([['I', 'am', 'a', 'sentence'], ['another', 'sentence']], dtype=object)
    string_dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)
    h5py_file.create_dataset("sentences", data=data, dtype=string_dt)
```

Comment: `TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent` - your reference has nothing to do with HDF files