# Input a list of arrays of numbers in h5py

Tags: python, arraylist, hdf5, h5py

I was trying to input a list of numeric arrays into an HDF5 file using h5py. Consider for example:

```
f = h5py.File('tester.hdf5','w')
b = [[1,2][1,2,3]]
```

This throws an error.

```
TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent
```

So I am assuming HDF5 doesn't support this.

Like you can store a list of strings by using a special datatype, is there a way for list of numeric array as well.

[H5py store list of list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873311/h5py-store-list-of-list-of-strings)

If not, what are the other suitable ways to store a list like this which I can access later from memory.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: I can `pickle.dump` it, I guess. But I am trying to fit a huge dataset in a single file. It would help if HDF5 can take it in, and thats where I got curious about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could split your list of lists in seperate datasets and store them seperately:

```
import h5py
my_list = [[1,2],[1,2,3]]
f = h5py.File('tester.hdf5','w')
grp=f.create_group('list_of_lists')
for i,list in enumerate(my_list):
    grp.create_dataset(str(i),data=list)
```

After doing so, you can slice trough your datasets like before with a little variation:

```
In[1]: grp[str(0)][:].tolist()
Out[1]: [1, 2]
In[2]: grp[str(1)][:].tolist()
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: A small number of added code lines, but this seems like a viable way to do it. Thanks.