# CSV via NumPy genfromtxt(): dtype for variable string sizes

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scipy, genfromtxt

I'm reading in a CSV using `genfromtxt()`, and I want all of my values to be strings. I need to specify a string `dtype` but specifying `S` results in empty strings:

```
In [83]: s = StringIO("a,b,c\n1,1.3,abcde\n2,4,hihihi")

In [84]: data = np.genfromtxt(s, dtype='S', delimiter=',', names=True)

In [85]: data
Out[85]: 
array([('', '', ''), ('', '', '')], 
      dtype={'names':['a','b','c'], 'formats':['S','S','S'], 'offsets':[0,0,0], 'itemsize':3})

In [86]: data['a']
Out[86]: 
array(['', ''], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

I think it's because arrays can't have variable length columns, and you need to specify something like `|S10`:

```
In [98]: data = np.genfromtxt(s, dtype=[(col, '|S10') for col in ('a', 'b', 'c')], delimiter=',', skip_header=1)

In [99]: data
Out[99]: 
array([('1', '1.3', 'abcde'), ('2', '4', 'hihihi')], 
      dtype=[('a', 'S10'), ('b', 'S10'), ('c', 'S10')])

In [100]: data['a']
Out[100]: 
array(['1', '2'], 
      dtype='|S10')
```

But what if I don't know the max string length per column going into this?

I know I can specify `dtype=None` and it'll "automagically" figure out the dtypes, but I want them all to be strings, and the above example will give ints/floats.

I also saw this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14639568/1406873 which suggests using python `object` dtype, but that seems to add too much overhead for my needs.

I'm thinking I could read through the entire CSV first, keeping track of the max column lengths, then call genfromtxt() with those lengths. Any other ideas?

References:

- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html
- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html
- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Comment: Did you try `dtype=str`?

Comment: @hpaulj I did indeed. It's the same as `dtype='S'`

Comment: _"using python object dtype"_ you basically get an array of references. Element access is a tad slower. _"keeping track of the max column lengths, then call genfromtxt() with those lengths"_ this is what I would do as well, but keep in mind that all your strings will be allocated the size of the largest one. This is not absolutely memory efficient either.

Answer (score -1):

`genfromtxt` treats `str` (or `np.str`) generically - at least in Py3

```
In [590]: np.genfromtxt(b"a,b,c\n1,1.3,abcde\n2,4,hihihi".splitlines(), dtype=str)
Out[590]: 
array(['a,b,c', '1,1.3,abcde', '2,4,hihihi'], 
      dtype='<U11')

In [591]: np.genfromtxt(b"a,b,c\n1,1.3,abcde\n2,4,hihihi".splitlines(),dtype=str, delimiter=',')
Out[591]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['1', '1.3', 'abcde'],
       ['2', '4', 'hihihi']], 
      dtype='<U6')
```