# Is there a way to return an ndarray of arbitrary length strings and dtype PyObject?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

Using Boost's (version >= 1.63) numpy extension to Boost-Python is there a way to return a numpy array of arbitrary length strings where `dtype = object`?  Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639496/python-numpy-array-of-arbitrary-length-strings) but in C++.

The following snippet works if string padding isn't an issue:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::python;
namespace np = boost::python::numpy;

np::ndarray get_numpy_array(){
    vector<string> strings = {"a","aa","aaa","aaaa"};
    bp::list py_list;
    for(auto& s: strings){
        py_list.append(s);
    }
    np::ndarray py_array = np::array(py_list);
    return py_array;
}
```

The return `dtype` is `<U4` in this toy example.  In practice I'll have strings ranging from one to several thousand characters and would prefer to avoid the cost of padding smaller strings.

Alternatively I could return a `boost::python::list` and handle the conversion back to a Numpy array in Python but I would prefer to avoid doing a double copy.