# Assigning "list of directory" array on numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I tried assigning a list of directories on a numpy array, but somehow the array only stores the first letter, not the full address of strings.

```
lasdir=np.array(range(4), dtype=str).reshape(2,2)
i=0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    for file in files:
        if (file.lower().endswith(".las")):
            lasdir[i,0]=file
            lasdir[i,1]=os.path.join(root, file)
            i=i+1
```

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When usings a `str` dtype, it uses fixed-length strings. As suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14639568/9291575), you're better off using dtype `object`.

So your first line could transform to :

```
lasdir = np.empty((2,2), dtype=object)
```