# replace strings in N-d numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

i have a 2d array of strings and i want to replace them with other strings that are bigger in length.
I tried this

```
for key, value in UniqueIds.items():
            indices[indices[...] == str(value)] = key
```

to replace each value with the corresponding key, but each value is 4 bytes and the key is about 10, and the changed value shows only the first 4 letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that i converted the initial array of ints to an array of strings like this :

```
indices = np.char.mod('%d', indices)
```

When i changed the line above with this one:

```
indices = indices.astype(str)
```

everything worked as expected.

Comment: ok ;-) still... check the `dtype` of `indices` - the resulting `dtype` will depend on what you had before calling `.astype(str)`. If it e.g. was `int32`, `dtype` is something like `<U11` - so you're still limited what you can put in.

Comment: Alright, thanks and I hope it will be helpful anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change the `dtype` of the array, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639496/how-to-create-a-numpy-array-of-arbitrary-length-strings) or also [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modify-numpy-array-to-store-an-arbitrary-length-string/). A 4-character string would be `dtype='<U4'`. If you'd have an 8-character string, it would be `dtype='<U8'` and so on.

So if you know the size of your resulting strings, you could specify it explicitly (e.g.`dtype='<U10'` to hold 10 Unicode characters). If you don't care about memory and copy operations, make it dynamic by using `object` as `dtype`:

```py
import numpy as np
s = np.array(['test'], dtype=object)
s[0] = 'testtesttesttest'
# s
# array(['testtesttesttest'], dtype=object)
```

now `.replace()` will work:

```py
s[0] = s[0].replace('test', 'notatest')
# s
# array(['notatestnotatestnotatestnotatest'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Technically `'U10' is 10 unicode characters, or 40 bytes as `numpy` implements it (`itemsize`).

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the clarification! Made an edit to reflect that.