# Numpy assign string to array of nans gives "ValueError: could not convert string to float"

Tags: python, numpy

I'm just failing to wrap my head around this. Basically it should be an easy thing to solve, but I'm not getting it right.

I set up an numpy array, and fill it with NaN values. Then I wanted to assign strings to it's fields (that is what I definitely want to do) I get "ValueError: could not convert string to float". All I found here in StackOverflow's search was how to convert the strings into floats - but that's not what I want to do.

Here's a small code example that describes what I'm talking about:

```
a = np.empty((6, 7))
a[:] = np.nan
# later in a loop
a[0,0] = 'abc'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying a dtype for the numpy array. `a = np.empty((6, 7), dtype=object)`. The above error occurs as the dtype of the array `a` is `float64`. When you are trying to assign a string to a float array `ValueError: could not convert string to float` has been raised.

For further reference : [How to create a numpy array of arbitrary length strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639496/how-to-create-a-numpy-array-of-arbitrary-length-strings)

If this solution is helpful, kindly do upvote the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for  ```dtype=object```