# How can I put a string to an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to put a string to an array location but I get an error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float

My code is the following:

```
k = np.ceil(99/8)

rs = np.zeros((int(k), 10))

for i in range(0, int(k)):
    rs[i, 0] = "FREQ"
    for j in range(1,9):
        rs[i, j] = rs_imp[8*k+j, 0]
```

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999617/how-to-assign-a-string-value-to-an-array-in-numpy) is what you are actually looking to perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is implicitly a float array, but you can change the data type to `object` to be able to include both floats and strings:

```
rs = np.zeros((int(k), 10), dtype='object')
```

**But** this is going to rob you of potential optimizations and may cause unexpected problems later on.

Sounds like an XY problem. Why do you think you need to add the string "FREQ" into this array? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: It is a XY problem that I want to separate and create files with specific format so that I can use the XY as an input.

Thank you very very much. It worked this way.

Comment: How can I write that array now to a .txt file though? When I tried to do

np.savetxt('test.txt', rsf, delimiter=',')

I got 

Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e')

Comment: Because the array is no longer of type `float`, the default formatting codes  (like `%e`) are not valid. You could do this: `np.savetxt('test.txt', rsf, delimiter=',', fmt='%s')` and it should do what you need, but if the point of the question was to add "FREQ" as a prefix to each line of a file containing numbers, there are cleaner ways to achieve this than to create a mixed-type array. By the way, an XY problem is defined [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of floats. You want to put a string value to an element of that array. It is not possible.