# Taking file input in numpy Matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am unable to find a method to take input of a given file in numpy matrix. 
I have tried the `np.loadtxt()` but was unable to get the data.

My file format is something like this: 
Number of col = 9 (except the first field all others are in float).

```
M,0.475,0.37,0.125,0.5095,0.2165,0.1125,0.165,9
F,0.55,0.44,0.15,0.8945,0.3145,0.151,0.32,19
```

I have also tried taking input in a list and then trying to make it numpy matrix but it was also a failure.

Comment: A numpy matrix can only hold one type of data, not strings and floats both: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999617/how-to-assign-a-string-value-to-an-array-in-numpy

Comment: @StefanS In that case is there a way to convert a 2D list of homogeneous type to numpy matrix?

Comment: What was wrong with the `loadtxt`?  error, results you don't understand?  What do you expect or want? How is the first column supposed to be handled?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using `pandas` instead - it's much better suited to homogeneous data, and its `read_csv` function will take your data file and convert it immediately to something you can work with.

You can give each column a name - if you don't do this, the function will interpret the first data row as column headings.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.read_csv("/tmp/data.txt",
                 names=['sex', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four',
                        'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight'])
>>> print(data)
  sex    one   two  three    four    five     six  seven  eight
0   M  0.475  0.37  0.125  0.5095  0.2165  0.1125  0.165      9
1   F  0.550  0.44  0.150  0.8945  0.3145  0.1510  0.320     19
```

Answer (score 1):

With your sample as a list of lines:

```
In [1]: txt=b"""
   ...: M,0.475,0.37,0.125,0.5095,0.2165,0.1125,0.165,9
   ...: F,0.55,0.44,0.15,0.8945,0.3145,0.151,0.32,19
   ...: """
In [2]: txt=txt.splitlines()
```

`genfromtxt` can load it with `dtype=None`:

```
In [16]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=',', dtype=None)
In [17]: data
Out[17]: 
array([(b'M', 0.475, 0.37, 0.125, 0.5095, 0.2165, 0.1125, 0.165, 9),
       (b'F', 0.55, 0.44, 0.15, 0.8945, 0.3145, 0.151, 0.32, 19)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S1'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<f8'), ('f6', '<f8'), ('f7', '<f8'), ('f8', '<i4')])
In [18]: data['f0']
Out[18]: 
array([b'M', b'F'], 
      dtype='|S1')
In [19]: data['f3']
Out[19]: array([ 0.125,  0.15 ])
In [20]:
```

The result is a 1d array (here 2 elements), with many fields, which are accessed by name.  Here the first is deduced to be a string, the rest float, except the last integer.

I could be more specific about the `dtype`, and define a field with multiple columns

```
In [21]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter=',',dtype=['S3','8float'])
In [22]: data
Out[22]: 
array([(b'M', [0.475, 0.37, 0.125, 0.5095, 0.2165, 0.1125, 0.165, 9.0]),
       (b'F', [0.55, 0.44, 0.15, 0.8945, 0.3145, 0.151, 0.32, 19.0])], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S3'), ('f1', '<f8', (8,))])
In [23]: data['f1']
Out[23]: 
array([[  0.475 ,   0.37  ,   0.125 ,   0.5095,   0.2165,   0.1125,
          0.165 ,   9.    ],
       [  0.55  ,   0.44  ,   0.15  ,   0.8945,   0.3145,   0.151 ,
          0.32  ,  19.    ]])
```

The `f1` field is a 2d array of shape (2,8).

`np.loadtxt` will also work, but it's `dtype` interpretation isn't as flexible.  Copying the `dtype` from the `genfromtxt` example produces the same thing.

```
 datal=np.loadtxt(txt,delimiter=',',dtype=data.dtype)
```

`pandas` also has a good csv reader, with more speed and flexibility.  It's a good choice if you are already working with pandas.